# Disabling Full Screen Mode In Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

When I press 'f11' the app will appear in the full-screen mood. How I can disable this option?

```js
function createWindow() {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
        width:610,
        height:679,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, APP_DIR, IMG_DIR, 'icon.png'),
        frame: false,
        resizable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    window.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, APP_DIR, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `fullscreenable` Boolean (optional) - Whether the window can be put
>   into fullscreen mode. On macOS, also whether the maximize/zoom button
>   should toggle full screen mode or maximize window. Default is true.

From: [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window)

```
window = new BrowserWindow({
        width:610,
        height:679,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, APP_DIR, IMG_DIR, 'icon.png'),
        frame: false,
        fullscreenable: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
```